# Where does minikube configure master node components?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

If i have installed K8S using minikube, where will the master node components be installed. (Ex: the api server, replication controller, etcd etc)
Is it in the host? or the VM? 
I understand the worker node is the VM configured by minikube

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is installed in the Virtual Machine. Based on the localkube project, it is creating an All-in-one single-node cluster.

More information here: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/cluster-lifecycle/local-cluster-ux.md

Comment: Thanks for that. I am actually figuring out how i can configure oidc with K8S in this setting. Is it even possible with minikube? I cant seem to find any file to modify inside the vm

Comment: Minikube is not the best option if you want to study the architecture or do operations like you describe. The only thing you can do is modify the startup options when creating the cluster: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#configuring-kubernetes

Comment: Could you suggest how i can have a minimum install of K8S to test oidc based authentication? It would be of great help

Comment: I would advise to use kubeadm with two Ubuntu nodes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: Can the 2 ubuntu nodes be VMs?

Comment: Yes, without issues

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I will start the installation with kubeadm right away :)

Comment: No problem :) If you think that the question is answered, could you please mark it so?

Comment: With this setup could you please tell me the location for the api server file?

Comment: In the /etc/Kubernetes/pki folder I think